# Convert uWSGI HTTP server to work behind Nginx instead

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm serving my app with uWSGI using `uwsgi --http-socket 127.0.0.1:3031 -w app:app`, which works when I go to `127.0.0.1:3031` in a browser.  I want to use Nginx, so I told it to `uwsgi_pass` to that url, but now I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.  How do I put uWSGI behind Nginx?

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /static/folder/location;
    }
}
```

```
2016/05/16 19:50:09 [error] 6810#0: *4 upstream prematurely closed
connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3031", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`socket`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#putting-behind-a-full-webserver), not `http-socket`.

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031 -w app:app
```

[`http-socket`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HTTP.html) makes uWSGI act like a web server that speaks HTTP, and is not correct if you're using Nginx, since it understands uWSGI directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http-socket between nginx and uWSGI.
For example, if you launch your python app with uWSGI:

```
uwsgi --http-socket 127.0.0.1:3031 --wsgi-file application.py --callable app --processes 4 --threads 2 --stats 127.0.0.1:9191
```

Configure Nginx with:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3031/;
}
```